# Where is FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute located?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

I've been reading about the extension points of azure functions using the function filters - https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters

However I'm stuck at the first hurdle of creating my own class that inherits `FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute`. I just can't find the type anywhere.

FYI - I'm also pointing at the nightly builds nuget feed (http://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v2)

Where is the `FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute` type located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the location of the `FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute`, It looks like it is part of the 2.x.x line of packages on the [nightly build feed](https://myget.org/feed/azure-appservice/package/nuget/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs) not the 3.x.x packages. Thus Updating to the latest pre-release package didn't contain the class.

For anyone interested - this is currently in the dev branch on the github project - https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Filters/FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute.cs

and also details on this functionality can be found on this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/980)

So to install the correct package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs -Version 2.1.0-beta1-10998
```

or

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs --version 2.1.0-beta1-10998
```

Comment: Anybody have any idea why FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute is still marked as obsolete?

Comment: @Brandon it looks like the feature was incomplete and that's why they applied the attribute.

"We are not removing Filters - we applied Obsolete attribute to those APIs because unfortunately we didn't have time to finish the feature before we had to release the v3 SDK."

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3401#issuecomment-426734218